# Switch between Android Driver and iOS Driver in a single test (Appium)

Tags: android, ios, testing, mobile, appium

I'm just trying to get a single test for both of Mobile Operative System

I'm using Cucumber as test framework for example that feature:

@test

Scenario Outline: Test app

```
When Start Test "<Platform>"
Then Do the test

Examples:
  | Platform |
  | Android  |
  | IOS      |
```

Calls to my Test.java:

```
public class Test {
  public <typeofvariable> driver;
  @When("Start Test {string}")
  public Start_test (String platform){
  if (platform.equals("Android"))
    {
        driver = new InitAndroidDriver();

    }
    else { driver = new InitIOSDriver();}
     
  }
  @When("Do the test")
  public Do_the_test{
    driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
  }

}
```

But I don't know what type of variable needs to be "driver" to accept AndroidDriver and also IOSDriver, I tried putting AppiumDriver in  but It not works for me, because in the "Do the test" section I need to switch between context and AppiumDriver dont seems to have that function.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself, it's a little bit tricky, but you would want it to implement that!

```
public class Test {
  public AppiumDriver driver;
  @When("Start Test {string}")
  public Start_test (String platform){
  if (platform.equals("Android"))
    {
        driver = new InitAndroidDriver();

    }
    else { driver = new InitIOSDriver();}
     
  }
  @When("Do the test")
  public Do_the_test{
   switchContext(driver,"NATIVE_APP",platform);
   //Some test here
   switchContext(driver,"WEBVIEW",platform);
 
  }


public static void switchContext (AppiumDriver driver, String context, String platform) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        int context_position = 0;
        if (context.equals("NATIVE_APP")) {context_position = 0;} else {context_position = 1;}
        if (platform.equals("Android"))
        {
                Set<String> contextNames = ((AndroidDriver)driver).getContextHandles();
                for (String contextName : contextNames) {
                    System.out.println("Contextos disponibles Android: " + contextName);
                }
                System.out.println("Contexto seleccionado: " + contextNames.toArray()[context_position]);
                ((AndroidDriver)driver).context((String) contextNames.toArray()[context_position]);
        }
        else {
            Set<String> contextNames = ((IOSDriver)driver).getContextHandles();
            for (String contextName : contextNames) {
                System.out.println("Contextos disponibles IOS: " + contextName);
            }
            System.out.println("Contexto seleccionado: " + contextNames.toArray()[context_position]);
            ((IOSDriver)driver).context((String) contextNames.toArray()[context_position]);
        }

    }
}
```